# Angular Unit testing: how to mock server sent events

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-service, server-sent-events

I have a angular service that wraps a server-sent events. How do I mock the server-sent events in unit testing? Can I use mockHttpbackend in this case?

Comment: You already have a service that wraps them, right? Mock it.

Comment: Check this http://blog.xebia.com/mocking-a-rest-backend-for-your-angularjs-grunt-web-application/

Comment: did you find anything ? we chose to use protractor to test it instead of unit tests as we couldn't find an easy way to mock EventSource.

Answer (score 0):

My hack:

create a MockEventSource

```
class MockEventSource {
  static lastInstance: MockEventSource;
  constructor(url: string) {
    MockEventSource.lastInstance = this;
  }

  onmessage: (message: any) => any;
}
```

register it on the window object

```
beforeEach(() => {
  window["EventSource"] = MockEventSource;
  MockEventSource.lastInstance = null;
});
```

and call onmessage on it:

```
MockEventSource.lastInstance.onmessage({ data: JSON.stringify(...) });
```